# I want to change the size of my PDF?

Tags: php, pdf, phantomjs

I am using Phantom js to create pdf in my application (using the export model, toPDF()) now the PDF works fine. But my CGridview get splitted into two pages which doesn't look fine. So I want to change the size of the PDF.

I searched for the available options and I get like (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) some attributes like papersize in this page. But it wasn't work on my page.

I tried to change the path variable in the export model and I add the size attribute as well. It doesn't work either. I need some solution to change the size of PDF.

Comment: What's happening when you define paperSize?  Are the dimensions of your output PDF changing, but the rendered HTML from CGridView isn't what you'd like?  Or some other behavior?

Comment: I placed the papersize attribute in a java script function which invoked when the print pdf button is clicked. But nothing else executed after the papersize call.